# Azure Stream Analytics: How can I update Query at runtime and Programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

Every time I have to update the query of the Stream-Analytics service, I have to first stop it, update the query, and then start it back again. And all of this is done manually from the Azure portal.

This was the initial phase when I was exploring and understanding the stream-analytics but now I have to take this to next level, For that, I would need the continuous updation of queries at runtime and I don't want to do it manually.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update query at runtime and programmatically. This is not supported by now. You can vote up and track this feature here.https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics/suggestions/13242726-provide-a-better-experience-for-updating-queries-w